# EXCEL: Some formulas not auto replicating

Tags: excel

I have a excel worksheet that has 6 rows of 12 at the top of the page as a reference table.  There are then 3 columns going down the left in which numbers are inserted by the user.  These inputs are then run through the various formulas in the columns to the right.  The problem is only about half of the formulas are autoreplicating down the page when you enter a new row of the 3 inputs and I can't figure out why some are and some aren't.

- The columns that aren't replicating are not directly beside each other, they are mixed in with ones that are replicating.
- I have selected the entire workbook and made sure cell formatting is set to general.  I have tried with the set to numbers as well.  All the cells formulas result in number data or true/false columns.  Some true/false columns are replicating, most are not.
- The true/false columns that aren't replicating I changed to try and output 1 or 0 and they still did not replicate.

Here is the list of formulas in the workbook that do replicate:

=IF(B50=0,FALSE,ISEVEN(B50))

=IF(B50=0,FALSE,ISODD(B50))

=IF(J50=TRUE,1,0)

=IF(B50=0,0,IF(B50<=18,1,0))

=IF(B50=0,0,IF(B50>=19,1,0))

=COUNTIF($B$1:$M$1,B50)

=COUNTIF($B$2:$M$2,B50)

=COUNTIF($B$3:$M$3,B50)

=COUNTIF($B$4:$M$4,B50)

=COUNTIF($B$5:$M$5,B50)

=COUNTIF($B$6:$M$6,B50)

And formulas that aren't auto replicating:

=IF((C50+C49+C48)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((D56+D55+D54)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((H56+H55+H54)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((K56+K55+K54)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((M56+M55+M54)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((O56+O55+O54)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((Q56+Q55+Q54+Q53+Q52+Q51)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((S56+S55+S54+S53+S52+S51)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((U56+U55+U54+U53+U52+U51)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((W56+W55+W54+W53+W52+W51)=0,TRUE,)

=IF((Y56+Y55+Y54+Y53+Y52+Y51)=0,TRUE,)

The first two of the not working list work directly from the inputs from the user which are numbers.  The rest work off the results of formulas in other cells.  I have tried changing these to =IF((C50+C49+C48)=0,TRUE,FALSE) or =IF((C50+C49+C48)=0,1,0) and they still won't replicate.

However the formulas DO work and I can drag the formulas down with the cross to fill the next line and they continue down correctly.  I just don't know why that bottom list isn't auto replicating so I don't have to drag down the line every time I put in a new line.  Again, they are not blocked together either.  They don't work in columns E, F, I, L, N, P, R, T, V, X, Z, AB.

Additional Info Edit:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AugdlkUwEcaQj0IBMRluryEJcY2t

Here is the file.  It's a roulette probability worksheet.  Open it up and go to the Run 2 tab.  You enter the number called on the left, and then a 1 for red or 1 for black.  For example, 35 is always black, so right now it is set up to enter 35 for the number, 0 since its not red, and 1 for black.

When you enter these numbers you see that it automatically brings down some of the formulas in the rest of the columns for that row.  However, none of the bet columns automatically move down like the others.  You can highlight the prior row and drag then down and it will auto fill correctly.  I would just like all the columns to move down so I don't have to pull the line down every time.

Comment: Have you tried something like `=not(sum(c48:c50))` ?

Comment: That doesnt replicate either.

Comment: You could use a `Worksheet_Change()` event to ensure it fills down upon new related data.

Comment: VB Scripting is a little out of my normal realm of use.  How would I make that?  It would need to run like, if change in any column D cell, drag down E:AB from the above row.  So change in D80, drag down E79:AB79.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "auto replicating". Can you share your file in an ad-free service like Dropbox or Onedrive and explain in context? Like: what do you enter? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Now, read carefully: Edit your question to post a link to your file, then post a comment to alert the followers of the question. Do NOT post links or additional info in comments.

Comment: @teylyn Additional info added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you have the rows 10 to 19 with static numbers and then hide them.

Excel will only auto-populate formulas down to the next row if there is a certain number of rows above the current row that has the same formula.

But that approach is rather unreliable and a bit outdated.

If you want formulas and formatting to be applied to the next row of data when a new row is entered, then you can transform your table to an Excel Table object with Insert > Table or Ctrl-T.

An Excel Table object has a special functionality, and will copy any formulas automatically into new rows of data.

Comment: Thank you!  The table works like a charm!

BTW, rows 10-19 are there just to provide information for the formulas in the first spins when starting the strategy.  Since it is predicated on something not happening so many times in a row, the ones in 10-19 basically provide "false" for all bets until information is actually provided via spins but aren't necessary to be seen.  Otherwise every time you start the strategy it would immediately tell you to bet.